# Php Warning: Socket_Read(): Unable To Read From Socket [104]

Tags: php, php-socket

```
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once '../includes/session.php';
require_once '../includes/connection.php';
require_once '../classes/logfile.php';
require_once '../classes/Tracker.php';
?>
<?php


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function mysql_prep($value)
{
    $magic_quotes_active = get_magic_quotes_gpc();
    $new_enough_php = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string"); // i.e. PHP >= v4.3.0
    if ($new_enough_php) { // PHP v4.3.0 or higher
        // undo any magic quote effects so mysql_real_escape_string can do the work
        if ($magic_quotes_active) {
            $value = stripslashes($value);
        }
        $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    } else { // before PHP v4.3.0
        // if magic quotes aren't already on then add slashes manually
        if (!$magic_quotes_active) {
            $value = addslashes($value);
        }
        // if magic quotes are active, then the slashes already exist
    }
    return $value;
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$address = '192.168.1.225'; // IP Address
$port = 9000; //Port


$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, getprotobyname('tcp'));
socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) or die("cannot bind to address.");
echo socket_strerror(socket_last_error());
socket_listen($sock, 20);
$i = 0;
while (1) {
    $result = $client[++$i] = socket_accept($sock);
    $input = socket_read($client[$i], 1024000);


    if ($result):
        $data = 'Thank you for your request!' . " \r\n";
        socket_write($client[$i], $data, 1024000);
    endif;


    socket_write($client[$i], $input, 1024000);
    //$finInput = mysql_prep($input);
    $finInput = $input;
    //$input = preg_replace('/\?\//', '?', $input);
    echo $finInput . "\r\n";

    $lf = new Logfile();
    $lf->write($finInput);

    $tracker = new Tracker();
    // split client request database
    //$data = '1204270959,Éîe}…Í}äÞÌ–wäŸÕíe,GPRMC,095929.000,A,0652.2527,N,07953.3028,E,0.53,219.64,270412,,,A*6E,F,imei:355689011882595,112+ä';
    $data_array = $tracker->splitdata($finInput);
    $location = $tracker->getlatlng($data_array[5], $data_array[7]);

    $newloc = array();

    $newloc['lat'] = $location['lat'];
    $newloc['lng'] = $location['lng'];
    $newloc['imei'] = $data_array[16];
    $newloc['signal'] = $data_array[15];
    $newloc['speed'] = $data_array[9];
    $tracker->addlocation($newloc);
    echo "\r\n";
    print_r($newloc);

    socket_close($client[$i]);
}
socket_close($sock);
?>
```

I'm using this script to get gps data from gps tracker via tcp and this above script working fine. But after couple of hours this script showing below php warning message.

```
PHP Warning: socket_read(): unable to read from socket [104]: Connection reset by peer in /var/www/gpssys/bin/deamon_test.php on line 41

Warning: socket_read(): unable to read from socket [104]: Connection reset by peer in /var/www/gpssys/bin/deamon_test.php on line 41
PHP Warning: socket_write(): unable to write to socket [32]: Broken pipe in /var/www/gpssys/bin/deamon_test.php on line 45

Warning: socket_write(): unable to write to socket [32]: Broken pipe in /var/www/gpssys/bin/deamon_test.php on line 45
PHP Warning: socket_write(): unable to write to socket [32]: Broken pipe in /var/www/gpssys/bin/deamon_test.php on line 51

Warning: socket_write(): unable to write to socket [32]: Broken pipe in /var/www/gpssys/bin/deamon_test.php on line 51
```

Please help me to fix this.

Thanks,